# Need help writing a batch file to read a MS Access .ldb lock file with null delimiters

Tags: parsing, batch-file, ms-access, command

I am trying to create a batch file to read a Microsoft Access .ldb lock file.  The lock file contains a list of computer names and user names. I want to extract the computer names and eventually run them against an external command.

The format of the batch file is a single row with 
(1) a computer name
(2) a NULL character (Hex 00)
(3) approximately 20 spaces
(4) the user name
(5) a NULL character
(6) approximately 20 spaces
repeating.

Example in Notepad++ with `(NUL)` representing Hex 00:

```
COMPUTER0123(NUL)                     Admin(NUL)                     COMPUTER0507(NUL)                     Admin(NUL)
```

I've tried several methods using `FOR` to read the file but can't get past the first computer name.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set file=database.ldb

for /F %%a in ('type %file%') do (
    echo %%a
    )
```

For for most of my Access databases, the user name in the file is `Admin`.  I've been able to use `FIND` to tell me how many occurrences of "Admin" are in the file (plus 1).

```
for /f "delims=" %%n in ('find /c /v "Admin" %file%') do set "len=%%n"
set "len=!len:*:=!"
echo %len% (minus 1) computer names to process 
<%file% (
  for /l %%l in (1 1 !len!) do (  
    set "line="
    set /p "line="
    echo(!line!)    
    )
)
```

Iterating through the found lines doesn't work, probably because there only is one line in the file (no carriage returns).

I would like to find a solution that would work with a standard install of Windows XP.

---

After receiving an accepted answer, I combined that into a batch file that I'm posting below.  I named the file `ShowUsersInLDB.bat` and put it in my *SendTo* folder.

```
@echo off
::===================================================================
:: Put this in your SendTo folder and it will let you right-click 
:: on an Access .ldb/.laccdb lock file and tell you the computer
:: names that have opened the database.  
::
:: After the computer names are shown, this will prompt you to 
:: search for the user names associated with each computer.  This
:: depends upon finding a 3rd party file named NetUsers.exe in
:: the user profile folder.  Feel free to change the path if you
:: want to store the file in another location.
:: 
:: NetUsers.exe can be downloaded from here:  http://www.optimumx.com/downloads.html#NetUsers
::
:: Notes:
:: 1) Keep in mind that sometimes after people leave the database 
:: the lock file still shows their computer name.  Don't jump
:: to conclusions.
:: 2) NetUsers.exe seems to report all users who have logged on
:: to the computer and not logged off, including services.  
:: If you aren't familiar with your user names or your users are
:: sharing remote desktops/Citrix/Terminal Services, you may have 
:: to guess who might have created the lock entry. 
::
:: Installation:
:: You may find a batch file named Install_UsersInLDB.bat that will 
:: copy this file to the SendTo folder and the NetUsers.exe file to 
:: the user profile (or a place you define).
::
:: Ben Sacherich - March 2014
:: Please let me know if you have any ideas for improvements.
::===================================================================

setlocal
set file="%1"

:: Make sure the file has a compatible extension.
if  "%~x1"==".ldb"    goto :ExtensionIsValid
if  "%~x1"==".laccdb" goto :ExtensionIsValid

echo.
echo "%~n1%~x1" is not the correct file type.
echo.
pause
goto :End

:ExtensionIsValid
echo The Access "%~n1%~x1" file contains
echo the following computer names:
echo.
set "compNameLine=1"
for /f %%A in ('more "%file%"') do (
  if defined compNameLine (
    echo %%A
    set "compNameLine="
  ) else set "compNameLine=1"
)

echo.
echo Are you ready to look up the user names on each computer?
pause

set "compNameLine=1"
for /f %%A in ('more "%file%"') do (
  if defined compNameLine (
    ::echo %%A
    "%userprofile%\netusers" \\%%A
    set "compNameLine="
  ) else set "compNameLine=1"
)

echo.
echo -- Validation finished at %time%  
pause
:End
exit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMD.EXE generally does not play nicely with NUL bytes. But there are a few external commands that can handle NUL bytes.

You also have to worry about the length of the "line". CMD.EXE does not like lines longer than 8191 bytes long.

I think your best bet is MORE since it converts NULs into new lines.

The following should echo your computer names.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "file=database.ldb"
set "compNameLine=1"
for /f %%A in ('more "%file%"') do (
  if defined compNameLine (
    echo %%A
    set "compNameLine="
  ) else set "compNameLine=1"
)
```

Comment: I was facing a problem handling nul characters too. Using more helped. Thanks for the tip!